# How do I detect whether or not an input with type=time has any values entered

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a javascript script that's supposed to detect whenever an html form input with `type="time"` has any value entered.

However, whenever I enter a partial value (for instance, type one number, instead of a full time with AM/PM), it doesn't detect the input as having a value.

In the below example, timeSelector is the input with `type="time"`.

```
if (timeSelector.value == "") {
    timeSelector.classList.add("empty");
} else {
    timeSelector.classList.remove("empty");
}
```

Is there any way to detect this type of thing?

To clarify, since apparently I didn't ask my question clearly enough, I need to detect when a `time` input has something entered, even if that something is an invalid or incomplete input.

Comment: Well that is because `"1"` it is an invalid time and invalid times do not return a value. That is how number, date, and time inputs work.

Comment: You still haven't posted enough for us to be able to help you. Where is the HTML? Where is the code that calls the `if` statement that you've posted? Where in your code is that bit of JavaScript located?

Comment: @epascarello Thank you for interacting with the actual question.
I see your point. My question is, how would I detect this type of partial/invalid input being there?
EDIT: to clarify, I'm referring to your question before the previous one.

Comment: If no value, check if it is invalid. There is no way to get the text out if it is invalid.

Comment: You may not think they are relevant, but we do. Without the complete picture of what you are doing, we have no way of knowing if your problem is a simple typo or something else entirely.

Comment: @epascarello Is there a way of checking if the text is there at all, whether or not it's valid?

Comment: You can argue all you want, but without the relevant code, all we can do is provide educated guesses. Instead of being argumentative, [why not learn how to use this platform](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the problem with html5 inputs is they do not give the text in the input if it is not valid. So you can use `checkValidity` when the user removes focus from the element.

```js
var checkInput = function() {
  var value = this.value
  var isValid = this.checkValidity()
  if (!this.value.length && isValid) {
    console.log('empty');
  } else if (!this.value.length && !isValid) {
    console.log('invalid time entered')
  } else {
    console.log('valid time entered')
  }
}

var input = document.querySelector("input")

input.addEventListener("input", checkInput)
input.addEventListener("blur", checkInput)
```

```html
<input type="time" />
```

Comment: Upon reading this answer, I've realised that I did not ask my question clearly enough. Your answer very clearly and concisely answers the question I *asked*, but unfortunately not the question I meant to ask. I have appended a clarification to the end of my question.

Comment: You can tell if something is entered, you just can not tell what was entered. Updated question with the 3 states.

Comment: That's very helpful. Thank you.
One note to mention is that this will not work if the element is required, so it might be good to set `this.required = false` before checking validity, and `this.required = true` after.

Comment: This doesn't give the correct answer in Safari (macOS). In that case, `input.checkValidity()` returns `true` when partial data is entered into a non-required field (which sort-of feels okay - the data is not required, therefore it's deemed to be empty). Doesn't help me though.

Answer (score 0):

Per the specification on `Input Elements` with type `time` ( [HTML Spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#time-state-(type=time)) ) :

> The value attribute, if specified and not empty, must have a value that is a valid time string.
>
> If the value of the element is not a valid time string, then set it to the empty string instead.

This means that `input` and `change` events don't occur until the entire time field has been filled out. Why? Because nothing really *has* changed.

You may think that you can circumvent this by using `keydown` or `keyup` events, but this is simply not the case.

The value is **not** changed and is therefore inaccessible until a full string that is capable of being parsed as a time is inside the time input box.

By filling in the below example you can see how the events fire. Notice the lack of `value` until *everything* is filled in.

```js
let i = document.querySelector("input"),
on = type => i.addEventListener(type, function() { console.log(`${type}, value: ${i.value}`); });

on("keydown");
on("keyup");
on("change");
on("input");
```

```html
<input type="time">
```

---

The only way to possibly get around the lack of a changing value is to set a default value as below:

```js
let i = document.querySelector("input"),
on = type => i.addEventListener(type, function() { console.log(`${type}, value: ${i.value}`); });


on("change");
```

```html
<input type="time" value="00:00">
```

However, with a default value there is a risk that the user will submit a time that isn't something that you'd likely want.

You could write some validation code to take care of this depending on the complexity of your functionality this may be possible.

Overall **if this is something you *need*** and the functionality is a bit more complicated than you think you can handle validating yourself, it would be best to either create your own time input interface from other input types, or to use a library or UI kit from a source that has already done the legwork.

---